# 4.x: Communication between custom widgets

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

How to make custom widgets communicate with each other in ArcGIS JavaScript 4.x?

To elaborate, when a button clicked on first custom widget it should update a label in the second custom widget and vice versa.

Comment: Please update your question including the code you want to be helped with. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask question correctly

Comment: use promises & also post an example for detailed answer